# How can I modify (but not replace) icons associated to file extensions?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, icons, user-experience

I'm developing a WPF desktop application for windows. It uses its own file type, let's say .foo. This file type represents a file that has been modified by the app. For example, it was originally a .txt but now it is .txt.foo (or maybe I can use .txtfoo).

I'd like to show a small app logo on top of the original icon, similar to what source control systems do (for example showing a small lock on top of the original icon).

I don't want to make completely new icons because I don't want to confuse the user and I'd like them to see the icon they already knew before using the app. So I just want to add the small logo on top of the current icon, whatever it is at the moment.

Is this even possible?

Comment: It's possible. I personally would advise against it. It's like the modal dialog box - it seems like a good idea, but imagine the chaos if every developer on earth tried to do it. If the file is now going to be associated with your app, it should have your icon. Showing them a modified notepad icon, or a modified Wordpad icon, and not having it be openable in those apps would ***add*** to user confusion, not take away from it.

Comment: Thanks David. Good points, but: Your first point is not a problem. Im not trying to modify .txt icons, only .txtfoo, so it's reasonable to assume there won't be collisions. About the second one, in fact it will open with the original app in the end, after a process :) But anyways, this is an interesting discussion. Could you please help on how to do it?

Comment: You would need to do the following: Read the registry to determine which icon is currently in use. Use System.Drawing.Graphics to open it, modify it, and save it as a new icon, then write the proper registry setting to associate the file type with this icon.  THen you need to ensure your app has rights to do such things (not advisable). There is code on the web to show you how to do all of those. A full solution would be too much to post as an answer here. As such, I'm voting to close the question as "not a real question" because it's not fully answerable in it's current format. No offense...

Comment: Thanks for your help David. I would not say the question is not answerable, as James and yourself have proved ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a custom file type, you would have to have a modified icon for each file you intend to rename. Your .txtfoo rather than .txt.foo would be one solution if there aren't too many file types, when your installer runs, you could register your new file types in the registry and just install the modified icons. However, if there are a lot of them this becomes problematic. The [Get Registered File Types and Their Associated Icons in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GetFileTypeAndIcon.aspx) article on Code Project and [C#: Set File Type Association](http://mel-green.com/2009/04/c-set-file-type-association/) may be helpful for some of what you're trying to do.

Otherwise, it sounds like you are looking for an icon overlay handler. This approach would mean that you'd need to have a set of small icon overlays to represent the original types that would go on top of your base .foo icon. See the [Creating Icon Overlay Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/cc144123) article on MSDN for more information.